# setting date_created for woo product

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm entering all our products via the API. 
I'd like to update the date_created the customer see, and which control the "NEW" badge, but the api does not allow that.
I want the date to be the date we have for when the product was first on the market (It's DVD's)

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: You can change publish date from admin dashboard after product import.

Comment: For 1000 products? I guess I have to take mport the date into a custom field, then have a script to modify the database.

Comment: You can import product created date into custom field. You can assign that custom field to the product date.